# Inserting From a single Table into multiple tables while Normalizing the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, relational-database

Ok so i have a table with the following columns

```
col1        col2       col3
a            a          1
a            a          2
a            b          3
a            b          4
a            b          5
```

so i have to split the above mentioned table into multiple tables while keeping col1 and col2 in a separate table and a primary key to foreign key relation with col3 in another table. This is how it looks.

```
table1

Id        col1         col2


table2
id        col3        table1fk
```

I was able to split the table into two tables but it created the duplicate rows in the table1 and mapped them to single row in table2.
What i wanted to achieve was create a single distinct row in table1 and map them to multiple distinct rows in table2.

The query i used was.

```
Merge Into table1 As c
Using oldtable ON 1=0

When Not Matched By Target Then
Insert(col1,col2) Values(val1,val2)
Output Inserted.Id,oldtable.val3
Into table2(fktable1,col3);
```

What can i do differently to achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with `MERGE` so I'm proposing an alternative solution using two `INSERT` statements:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2)
        SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2 FROM tbl

    INSERT INTO table2(col3, table1fk)
        SELECT
            t.col3,
            t1.Id
        FROM tbl t
        INNER JOIN table1 t1
            ON t1.col1 = t.col1
            AND t1.col2 = t.col2

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
    DECLARE
            @ErrorNumber    INT,
            @ErrorMessage   NVARCHAR(4000),
            @ErrorState     INT,
            @ErrorSeverity  INT,
            @ErrorLine      INT

    SELECT
        @ErrorNumber    =   ERROR_NUMBER(),
        @ErrorSeverity  =   ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState     =   ERROR_STATE(),
        @ErrorLine      =   ERROR_LINE(),
        @ErrorMessage   =   ERROR_MESSAGE()

    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState)
    PRINT 'Error detected, transaction rolled back.'
END CATCH
```

The first one, `INSERT`s unique rows of `col1,col2` into `table1`.

The second one, performs a `JOIN` on `tbl` and `table1` to get the the FK from `table1`.

These two `INSERT` statements must be under one transaction only.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ceb65/2/0)

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Keep it simple instead of using MERGE. You don't need the UPDATE/DELETE functionality it provides so two INSERT statements should do the trick with minimal complications...

Comment: yeah it seems much simple and easier to understand than my approach. Really thanks for the help. it sucks delving into databases as an application developer.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.