# Merge 3 tables into a single one

Tags: sql, sql-server

Actually i got 14 SQL Server tables , and 11 of them could be reduced to 4 .

They got the same column names and values , and i can't find the solution to merge into one new table ( that i already created by a SELECT INTO FROM ) .
 And also is it possible to add an incremental counter to mark each line of new added data with an ID ?

Thank you for the help .

Comment: INSERT newtable SELECT columns FROM oldtable

Comment: did i get your right? you just want to put the data of several tables in one table? if so, UNION ALL might be your friend

Comment: Without any table structures I can't really answer with any degree of accuracy, but, use an insert, then select the columns from table 1 and use UNION ALL to select from the rest. For the ID use an IDENTITY(1,1).

Comment: check this  -     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32110676/inserting-from-a-single-table-into-multiple-tables-while-normalizing-the-databas

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO BigNewTable ( col1, col2, col3 )
SELECT col1, col2, col3 
FROM 
(
   SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table3
)
```

> add an incremental counter

Make a column an [`IDENTITY` column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property)

```
CREATE TABLE BigNewTable 
(  
 Id int IDENTITY(1,1),  
 Col1 varchar (20),  
 Col2 varchar (20),   
 Col3 varchar (20) 
);
```

Comment: @EstebanP.: should work also without subselect. I prefer this if i want to add additional functionality, for example remove duplicates

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to insert data from several source-tables into one destination-table, you could do it in a single statement by just joining the `SELECT`s with `UNION ALL`. 
If you add a column with IDENTITY(1,1) in your new destination table, this will do automatically insert IDs and would be your desired counter.
Column should be defined like: `ID int IDENTITY(1,1)`

```
INSERT INTO mynewtable  ( col1, col2 )
     SELECT col1, col2
       FROM oldtable1
  UNION ALL
     SELECT col1, col2
       FROM oldtable2
  UNION ALL
     SELECT col1, col2
       FROM oldtable4
  UNION ALL
     SELECT col1, col2
       FROM oldtable4
```